# Why does dropdown menu only work properly in header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just implemented a dropdown-menu that drops down when the user hovers/clicks the menu image.

However as soon as the user scrolls down to section2, then the dropdown stops to work properly. Either it simply does not drop down when the user hovers/clicks the dropdown image, or if it does, the menu items can't be clicked.

I can't see how the other sections can influence whether or not a fixed dropdown works.

Any suggestions?

thanks

```js
var main = function() {
  $(".dropdown img").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu").slideDown("slow");
  });

  $(".dropdown img").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu").slideDown("slow");
  });

  $(".dropdown ul").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp("slow");
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp();
    $(".dropdown img").removeClass("rotate");
  });

  $(".dropdown img").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".dropdown img").addClass("rotate");
  });

  $(".dropdown-menu").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".dropdown img").removeClass("rotate");
  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

/*Header*/
.dropdown img {
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 3.5em;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.header {
  background: url(/img/sri.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(125, 132, 145, 0.6);
  min-height: 100%
}
.header ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}
.header .logo {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0.42em;
}
#rowheader {
  margin-top: 5em;
}
.header .dropdown {
  margin-top: 0.42em;
  position: fixed;
  right: 2em;
}
.dropdown img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
  /* Safari */
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, transform 1s;
}
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.dropdown ul {
  left: -8em;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
.header .logo p {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#rowheader h1 {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
/*Section1*/

#section1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
#section1 h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 2.5em 1em;
  display: block;
}
#section1 p {
  line-height: 1.8em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
#section1 a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #007bb6;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
#section1 a:hover {
  background: #005983
}
/*Section2*/

#section2 {
  line-height: 1.8em;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  position: relative;
}
#section2 h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 2.5em 1em;
  display: block;
}
#section2 p {
  padding: 0 0 0.5em;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}
#section2 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#img-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#img-wrapper img {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
#img-wrapper img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* Opera */
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Header -->
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <p>???</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <img src="img/menuwhite.jpg">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Find me on Linkedin</a>
          <li>
            <li><a href="#">Send me an email</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" download="Resume">Download my resume</a>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="rowheader">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Section1 -->
<div id="section1" class="container">
  <h2>About</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <h3>Me</h3>
      <p>blablablabla</p>
         <p>blablablablablablablablablqblablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Section2 -->
    <div id="section2" class="container">
      <h2>My Projects</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <div id="img-wrapper">
            <a href="" "><img src=" ""></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing z-index on `.header .dropdown` element

```
.header .dropdown {
    margin-top: 0.42em;
    position: fixed;
    right: 2em;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: Did the job! Thanks @Kantoci!